# Day Difference is not working properly due to timezone conversion

Tags: postgresql

I was working on a problem where we are creating a view. We have a task & the task has an estimated time put up by the creator, assigned_at, due_date. We need to distribute the estimated time b/w assigned_at to due_date. What I was doing is getting the days using the extract function and dividing the estimated time with days count. By default, we store timestamps as UTC. The days count not coming correctly.

```
Eg: A task has,
Due Date: 2022-03-24T18:30:00+00:00,
Assigned Date: 2022-03-23T20:09:57.028525+00:00,
Estimated Time: 10 //time to complete that task,
Per Day Estimated Time: 10(Estimated Time)/2 (No Of Days)=5
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_task_estimated_time(start_date timestamp with time zone, end_date timestamp with time zone, total_estimate numeric)
     RETURNS numeric
     LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$
    declare
        date_duration numeric;
    begin
        date_duration = extract(days from age(end_date, start_date));
    -- If due date is less than assigned date
        if (date_duration < 0) then
            return 0;
        end if;
    
        case
    -- For the same day
            when date_duration = 0 then
                date_duration = 1;
            else
                date_duration = date_duration + 1;
            end case;
    
        return total_estimate / date_duration;
    end;
    $function$
```

Here when we pass the UTC formatted date to the function named "get_task_estimated_time". We dont get the exact day difference (use the example that we given above)

Comment: AGE() returns an interval. Change date_duration to an interval as well and you can make a comparison without the usage of EXTRACT().

Comment: That is because the `age` of your two dates is `22:20:02.971475` or less then a day so you get `0` from the `extract`. I would say change to `extract(hours...)` and then divide the result by `24.0` to make 'days'. Make sure when you do the division you do `22/24.0` to get decimal results. Then you can use `ceiling` to get to move up to nearest integer: `select ceiling(22/24.0); 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Per the information in my comment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_task_estimated_time(start_date timestamp with time zone, end_date timestamp with time zone, total_estimate numeric)
 RETURNS numeric
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    declare
        date_duration numeric;
    begin
        date_duration = ceiling(extract(hours from age(end_date, start_date))/24.0);
        RAISE NOTICE 'date duration = %', date_duration;
    -- If due date is less than assigned date
        if (date_duration < 0) then
            return 0;
        end if;

        case
    -- For the same day
            when date_duration = 0 then
                date_duration = 1;
            else
                date_duration = date_duration + 1;
            end case;

        return total_estimate / date_duration;
    end;
    $function$

select get_task_estimated_time('2022-03-23T20:09:57.028525+00:00', '2022-03-24T18:30:00+00:00', 10);
NOTICE:  date duration = 1
 get_task_estimated_time 
-------------------------
      5.0000000000000000
```

The primary change being:

`ceiling(extract(hours from age(end_date, start_date))/24.0)`

which converts the `age` into hours and then divides by `24.0` to get decimal division and then applies `ceiling` to move the value up to the next highest integer.

Not sure it is necessary to return full `numeric`. `integer` would work if you are only interested in full days or a constrained `numeric`, say `numeric(5,2)`.